# How to increment primary key without using Auto Increment in MySql

Tags: mysql, linq-to-sql

I am having a table called Tl which consists of fields ID,Name and Course.
In my view when i click ADD DETAILS button i should be able to fill name and course and save it DB.
Here my ID is primary key.But i am not using AutoIncrement for this field.Without using increment option i should be able to save the newly added values.
Can any one suggest me how to implement this using linq query.
Thanks!

Comment: Please add some code, we definetely can't help withoud code.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with asp.net-mvc when it has strictly nothing to do with this framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suppose that you're using EntityFramework

```
var dbMaxId = context.TIs..Max(m => (int?) m.ID);
model.ID = dbMaxId + 1;
```

Comment: Hi,,thanks for the solution,here in model.ID in place of model i gave my model name but it is not accepting.Any solution to this.

Comment: public ActionResult Saving(IEnumerable<Val> us)
        {  TI u = new TI();   foreach (var k in us)
            { var s = dbContext.TI.Max(m => (int?)m.TI);Val.ID = dbMaxId + 1;u.Name=k.Name;u.Course=k.Course;